# How to create an epub from javascript?

Tags: javascript, epub

I am trying to create en ePub using the JSZIP javascript library but the output (i.e. epub.epub file) is not usable/reable

The following code does not work :

```
  // Create a new ZIP file
    var zip = new JSZip();

    // Set the metadata for the book
    var metadata = '<?xml version="1.0"?>' +
        '<package xmlns="http://www.idpf.org/2007/opf">' +
        '  <metadata>' +
        '    <dc:title>My Book</dc:title>' +
        '    <dc:author>John Smith</dc:author>' +
        '  </metadata>' +
        '  <manifest>' +
        '    <item id="text" href="text.txt" media-type="application/xhtml+xml"/>' +
        '    <item id="toc" href="toc.ncx" media-type="application/x-dtbncx+xml"/>' +
        '  </manifest>' +
        '  <spine>' +
        '    <itemref idref="text"/>' +
        '  </spine>' +
        '</package>';
    zip.file("content.opf", metadata);

    // Set the table of contents for the book
    var toc = '<?xml version="1.0"?>' +
        '<ncx xmlns="http://www.daisy.org/z3986/2005/ncx/" version="2005-1">' +
        '  <head>' +
        '    <meta name="dtb:uid" content="book-id"/>' +
        '    <meta name="dtb:depth" content="1"/>' +
        '    <meta name="dtb:totalPageCount" content="0"/>' +
        '    <meta name="dtb:maxPageNumber" content="0"/>' +
        '  </head>' +
        '  <docTitle>' +
        '    <text>My Book</text>' +
        '  </docTitle>' +
        '  <navMap>' +
        '    <navPoint id="navpoint-1" playOrder="1">' +
        '      <navLabel>' +
        '        <text>Chapter 1</text>' +
        '      </navLabel>' +
        '      <content src="text.txt#xpointer(/html/body/p[1])"/>' +
        '    </navPoint>' +
        '    <navPoint id="navpoint-2" playOrder="2">' +
        '      <navLabel>' +
        '        <text>Chapter 2</text>' +
        '      </navLabel>' +
        '      <content src="text.txt#xpointer(/html/body/p[5])"/>' +
        '    </navPoint>' +
        '  </navMap>' +
        '</ncx>';
    zip.file("toc.ncx", toc);

    // Add the text of the book to the ZIP file
    

    // Add the text of the book to the ZIP file
    zip.file("text.txt", "Chapter 1\n\nThis is the text for chapter 1.\n\nChapter 2\n\nThis is the text for chapter 2.");

    // Generate a downloadable EPUB file from the ZIP file
    zip.generateAsync({ type: "blob" })
        .then(function (blob) {
            saveAs(blob, "epub.epub");
        });
```

Could you please help me find a solution or redirect toward an existing library ?

I want to be able to use it within a chrome extension, I tried jEpub but it is blocked by chrome.

Comment: Can you be a little bit more specific, what does not work? Do you get an error message (in the developer tools or elsewhere), don't you get the desired result (what's wrong or missing), don't you get any result or is it invalid/unusable?

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of issues with your EPUB generation which would suggest you haven't read through the OPF specification which can be found here: https://idpf.org/epub/30/spec/epub30-ocf.html

The (main) issues are:

1. Missing metadata file
2. Incorrect structure (best practice)
3. OPF file missing version `package version`
4. You're using the dc namespace without it being defined. Define it.
5. Missing required dc elements such as `dc:identifier`.
6. `dc:author` doesn't exist as an element. Use `dc:creator` instead
7. Your spine should declare `toc="toc"`
8. Pages should be of type `.xhtml`
9. You should also include a nav file

Here is a working version of your script:

```
var zip = new JSZip();

// Set the metadata for the book
var mimetype = 'application/epub+zip';
zip.file("mimetype", mimetype);

var container = '<?xml version="1.0"?>' +
    '<container version="1.0" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:container">' +
    '  <rootfiles>' + 
    '    <rootfile full-path="OEBPS/content.opf" media-type="application/oebps-package+xml" />' + 
    '  </rootfiles>' + 
    '</container>';
zip.file("META-INF/container.xml", container);

var metadata = '<?xml version="1.0"?>' +
    '<package version="3.0" xml:lang="en" xmlns="http://www.idpf.org/2007/opf" unique-identifier="book-id">' + 
    '  <metadata xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">' +
    '    <dc:identifier id="book-id">urn:uuid:B9B412F2-CAAD-4A44-B91F-A375068478A0</dc:identifier>' + 
    '    <meta refines="#book-id" property="identifier-type" scheme="xsd:string">uuid</meta>' + 
    '    <meta property="dcterms:modified">2000-03-24T00:00:00Z</meta>' + 
    '    <dc:language>en</dc:language>' +
    '    <dc:title>My Book</dc:title>' +
    '    <dc:creator>John Smith</dc:creator>' +
    '  </metadata>' +
    '  <manifest>' +
    '    <item id="text" href="text.xhtml" media-type="application/xhtml+xml"/>' +
    '    <item id="toc" href="../OEBPS/toc.ncx" media-type="application/x-dtbncx+xml"/>' +
    '  </manifest>' +
    '  <spine toc="toc">' +
    '    <itemref idref="text"/>' +
    '  </spine>' +
    '</package>';
zip.file("OEBPS/content.opf", metadata);

// Set the table of contents for the book
var toc = '<?xml version="1.0"?>' +
    '<ncx xmlns="http://www.daisy.org/z3986/2005/ncx/" version="2005-1">' +
    '  <head>' +
    '    <meta name="dtb:uid" content="urn:uuid:B9B412F2-CAAD-4A44-B91F-A375068478A0"/>' +
    '    <meta name="dtb:depth" content="1"/>' +
    '    <meta name="dtb:totalPageCount" content="0"/>' +
    '    <meta name="dtb:maxPageNumber" content="0"/>' +
    '  </head>' +
    '  <docTitle>' +
    '    <text>My Book</text>' +
    '  </docTitle>' +
    '  <navMap>' +
    '    <navPoint id="navpoint-1" playOrder="1">' +
    '      <navLabel>' +
    '        <text>Chapter 1</text>' +
    '      </navLabel>' +
    '      <content src="text.xhtml#xpointer(/html/body/section[1])"/>' +
    '    </navPoint>' +
    '    <navPoint id="navpoint-2" playOrder="2">' +
    '      <navLabel>' +
    '        <text>Chapter 2</text>' +
    '      </navLabel>' +
    '      <content src="text.xhtml#xpointer(/html/body/section[2])"/>' +
    '    </navPoint>' +
    '  </navMap>' +
    '</ncx>';
zip.file("OEBPS/toc.ncx", toc);

// Add the text of the book to the ZIP file


// Add the text of the book to the ZIP file
var text = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>' + 
    '<!DOCTYPE html>' + 
    '<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:epub="http://www.idpf.org/2007/ops" xml:lang="en" lang="en">' + 
    '  <head>' + 
    '    <title>My Book</title>' + 
    '  </head>' + 
    '  <body>' + 
    '    <section><h1>Chapter 1</h1>' + 
    '      <p>This is the text for chapter 1.</p>' + 
    '    </section>' + 
    '    <section><h1>Chapter 2</h1>' + 
    '      <p>This is the text for chapter 2.</p>' + 
    '    </section>' +
    '  </body>' + 
    '</html>';
zip.file("OEBPS/text.xhtml", text);

// Generate a downloadable EPUB file from the ZIP file
zip.generateAsync({ type: "blob" }).then(function (blob) {
  saveAs(blob, "epub.epub");
});
```

Ensure that you also run your generated EPUB against a validator to debug. Something like https://draft2digital.com/book/epubcheck/upload is good.